# Get RealmObject attribute asynchronously

Tags: android, realm

I have a conversation RealmObject which contains a RealmList of messages (My messages don't know about the conversations). I want to query and sort them asynchronously.
Here is my awful attempt but I post it to give you a better idea of ​what I want to do :

```
return realm.where(Conversation.class)
            .equalTo("id",conversationId)
            .findFirstAsync()
            .getMessages().sort("receivedDate", Sort.DESCENDING)
            .asFlowable();
```

It doesn't work and this exception has been thrown:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The pending query has not been executed

Currently I have no idea how to query them asynchronously and get back them in the UI thread without changing my schema.

**Edit:**
My schema is very simple :

```
public class Message extends RealmObject{
private String content;
private Date receivedDate;
}

public class Conversation extends RealmObject{
    private String id;
    private RealmList<Message> messages;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your schema so I can't know if this is possible with linking objects, I guess I'd try the following

```
return realm.where(Conversation.class)
        .equalTo("id",conversationId)
        .findFirstAsync()  // maybe use findAllAsync instead? 
        .asFlowable()
        .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
        .switchMap(conversation -> 
              conversation.getMessages().where().findAllSortedAsync("receivedDate", Sort.DESCENDING)
                .asFlowable()
                .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded));
```

If the object can be deleted, then you might want to switch over to findAll* or check against isValid as well.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It works ! I completly forgot that realm allows to query a result.

Comment: I think I can add a linking object "Conversation" in my Message class, but what would be the difference with a Conversation object without the linking object annotation ?

Comment: You could probably just do `realm.where(Message.class).equalTo("conversation.id", conversationId).findAllSortedAsync("receivedDate", Sort.DESCENDING).asFlowable().filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)` if you add a linking objects named `conversation`.

Comment: If I add a conversation object without the linking annotation and set the conversation manualy, it would work too ? What linking annotation do is it set the object automaticaly right ? Maybe the difference is in the performance ?

Comment: Automatic linking is faster than manual.  for linking objects, you need Realm 3.5.0+

Comment: Thank you for your quick and useful answer :)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce
Can you give me a reason why the `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The pending query has not been executed` is throwing?

`Flowable<VideoDescriptionModel> videoDescription(String videoId) {

        Realm mRealm = mDatabaseHelper.provideRealm();
        if (mRealm != null) {
            RealmQuery<VideoDescriptionModel> query = mRealm.where(VideoDescriptionModel.class)
                            .equalTo(DatabaseConstants.VIDEO_ID, videoId);

            return query.findFirstAsync().asFlowable();

        }
    }`

I'm doing this and try video.getDescription()

Comment: Just don't use `findFirstAsync()`, like, ever

Comment: Oh I used it in this answer. Yeah I'd really just say one should prefer to use `findAllAsync()` instead if able.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `LiveDataReactiveStreams`

```
LiveDataReactiveStreams.fromPublisher(realm.where(Conversation.class)
        .equalTo("id",conversationId)
        .findFirstAsync()
        .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
        .getMessages().sort("receivedDate", Sort.DESCENDING)
        .asFlowable()))
            .getValue();
```